# No keyboard after factory reset. Can't install keyboard on phone with bluetooth, google play, sd card, etc

Tags: keyboard, factory-reset

I have a Coolpad Quattro with Gingerbread 2.3. I didn't like the keyboards that came with the phone so I deleted them and got another one from the app store.
Because my phone was running slowly, I did a factory reset. This is the second time I did it.
Only this time, it didn't restore my keyboards. Now I have no keyboard to use, and I cannot sign into the play store on my phone, so I can't install a keyboard from Google Play. I have tried to send a file via bluetooth, but that doesn't seem to work either. I really need to use my keyboard, and I have reset the phone three times now. What can I do?

Answer (score 6):

You just created a nice chicken-and-egg problem: to install a keyboard via the playstore, you need to configure your Google account on the device first. To do that, you need a keyboard. Note: never delete the (last) keyboard app from the system apps; a factory-reset removes *all* user apps, so if there is no keyboard app as *system* app...

Here's what you can do -- provided you've got some keyboard as `.apk` file:

1. enable *USB Debugging* on your device
2. use `adb install keyboard.apk` to install the keyboard app

If you don't have ADB installed on your computer, either install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/) -- or see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for an "ADB lite" variant.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve done it without adb or anything else. Just download this apk: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-keyboard/google-keyboard-4-0-21173-1568296-android-apk-download/

Then pass the apk to a second phone. After that pass by bluetooth the apk from the second phone to the first. After that the installation option will apear and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Following this advice I enabled USB Debugging (on my Moto g 2nd gen) and then I happened (on a whim) to look at Accounts before proceeding. At the bottom of the screen it said I could add an account so I went to do this - and there, suddenly was a keyboard again! So I was able to sign back into my Google account and get things working. I don't know if I have hit upon some safety feature, or what, but more importantly - it worked!

Answer (score -1):

Just get a free keyboard.APK and copy this to your SDcard. Install it from there.
To find a free keyboard APK file: Just do a search on Google: "free android keyboard apk".