# Unable to pass through setup wizard

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, nexus-6, hard-reset, setup-wizard

I had deleted the Google keyboard app and was using a third party keyboard app on my Motorola Nexus 6. Just now, I hard reset my phone and come to know that there is no default keyboard installed; making me unable to pass through the setup wizard. I am running Android 5.1.1 and because of factory reset protection, it's a must to pass through setup wizard, can't skip anything. Please help me fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your nexus 6 rooted?

Comment: I have installed kingroot on nexus 6 and deleted default keyboard app forever..but after dat through kingroot i have uprooted my phone again..so now don't have idea if it is rooted or not.. Phone is stucked on setup wizard only

Comment: Related: [No keyboard after factory reset. Can't install keyboard on phone with bluetooth, google play, sd card, etc](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44964/16575)

Comment: Unlock bootloader (if not done already), flash TWRP, download Google Keyboard's APK from somewhere and through TWRP, push it under /system/app/. Reboot to Android OS and the app would auto install during the reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are currently in an unknown state, the "best" option here is to reflash the factory images manually. Google provides factory images and instruction on their [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) page, and you could also upgrade to 6.0.1 if you wanted to.

Going through this procedure will return your Nexus device to it's factory condition, except with the version of software you chose to install.

Comment: Thanks for your advice i will try this option and let u know about results... Thank you