# My keyboard got removed when updating to Android 8 Oreo

Tags: keyboard, ota-update, 8.0-oreo

Yesterday I updated my Samsung S7 (SM-G930F) to Android Oreo version 8.0.0.
After the update I do not have any keyboard, just the Google's Voice Typing is showing up when I would like to type something.
Before I had the original Samsung swedish keyboard that came with the phone.

The numpad is working when I'm looking for typing number e.g. when dialing.
But whenever I need to type something else than just numbers, I do not have a keyboard.

Under settings -> Keyboard: There is only Googles Voice Typing and I have tried everything without any luck.

I do not want to reset the phone to default.

Anyone got any hints what to try?
Remember that it is very hard to try anything without a keyboard...

(All is in swedish so the translation might not be the correct one)

[image]

Comment: which keyboard you've used previously? please check settings-> apps-> keyboard app, check whether it is disabled or not.

Comment: I can not find anything in -> apps that has to do with a keyboard.

Comment: I don't think that it is swedish keyboard, may be samsung keyboard or google's gboard.

Comment: You can download this [Samsung Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.inputmethod&hl=en_US). It supports Swedish

Comment: have you found any keyboard app in app launcher or settings->applications->applications manger. Otherwise you can try Izzy's answer on this link(N.B: backup is recommended). https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44964/no-keyboard-after-factory-reset-cant-install-keyboard-on-phone-with-bluetooth

Comment: Thanks Rahul Gopi and beeshyams - 
Since I could only "type by voice" I didn't manage to find the Samsung Keyboard, but I manage to install gboard so now I at least have a keyboard to work with, eventhough it is not as good as the normal Samsung keyboard I'm used to...

Comment: happy to hear that the issue is solved. Normally, the keyboard app on device will be a system app(installed factory). You cannot uninstall system app or it don't get removed after OTA update / factory reset. you can just disable/enable it.

Comment: Well, my Samsung keyboard app was factory installed by Samsung and somehow it still got removed with the system update. Very strange and annoying.

Comment: Now that you have Gboard , you can go ahead and install the Samsung Keyboard and if that helps you, please go ahead and self answer :). It may help someone with similar issue

Comment: I've tried, but I actually have a hard time finding the Samsung Keyboard in Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as Rahul Gopi and beeshyams commented.

But since I could only "type by voice" I didn't manage to find the Samsung Keyboard, but I manage to install Google Gboard so now I at least have a keyboard to work with.

So now it would be easier to try to install my normal Samsung keyboard...